# jQuery / Rails: Fire JS event on submit; only when validation is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

In rails, some forms get validated on client-side automatically, so that the form doesn't get submitted when inappropriate values are in the form fields. You get something like[image: rails form validation]

I want to fire a javascript event (reveal a spinning loader in this case) but only when this *doesn't* happen, and the form actually gets submitted.

At the moment I have

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#new_import').on("submit", function () {
    $('#product_import_loading').slideDown();
  });
});
```

but this fires even when validation prevents submission.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are no inherent `jquery-ujs` events regarding form validation, but you can easily use something like [jQuery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) to do something only when the form passes client-side validation.

This would probably suit your needs (I don't have much experience with the plugin):

```
$("#new_import").on('submit', function() {
  if($(this).valid()) {
    // show your spinner
  }
  else {
    // do other stuff
  }
});
```